# SQL query based on two values in a column with a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

So here is what I'm attempting to accomplish. I want to have returned all rows within a specified date range where the value in a column is one value 'C' or another 'X'. I'm not huge in SQL and much more comfortable in scriptwriting for excel or google sheets. I would assume there's a pretty simple solution but here is what I have written so far that's not working.

```
Declare @FromDate DateTime
Declare @ToDate   DateTime

Set @FromDate='20201027'
Set @ToDAte  ='20201102'

select * from oehdr where OrderStatus='C' or OrderStatus='X'
```

The errors I've received have been "Invalid SQL, No Memory" and a script error when I modify the current attempt.

Comment: Looks like SQL Server (MS SQL) code, not MySQL...

Comment: There's no correlation between the variables you've got declared and the query that is written. That aside, the query itself has no obvious issue. Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough info in the question. We don't know the name of the date column, or whether the time is included, or whether the `ToDate` value is inclusive of the whole day. It's not even 100% clear exactly what DB you're using, as there's some conflicting info with the question.

But I'll do the best I can making some guessues:

```sql
Declare @FromDate DateTime = '20201027'
Declare @ToDate   DateTime = '20201102'

SELECT * 
FROM oehdr 
WHERE OrderStatus IN ('C', 'X')
    AND OrderDate >= @FromDate AND OrderDate < DATEADD(day, 1, @ToDate)
```

Notice I did *not* use the `BETWEEN` operator. `BETWEEN` is inclusive at both ends of the range, which is rarely what I want for dates. Instead, when I want the full day, I add one day and use an *exclusive* condition for the end of the range.